# Scope Issue: Not successfully storing accounts after using web3.eth.getAccounts()

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, addresses, accounts, dapp-design

I am having trouble with the following code:

```
var accounts = []

let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts((error, result) => {
    accounts = result;
    console.log(accounts);
});
console.log(accounts);
```

The first time I `console.log(accounts)`, the accounts are successfully retrieved, but when I `console.log(accounts)` in the final line of code, I still get an empty array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `accounts = result`, which then gets overwritten by the return of the function, which is nothing.

Instead, simply return `result` from the function rather than setting it:

```
var accounts = []

let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts((error, result) => {
    console.log(result);
    return result;
});
console.log(accounts);
```

Another option is to set `accounts` within the function and not return anything from the function itself:

```
var accounts = []

await web3.eth.getAccounts((error, result) => {
    accounts = result;
    console.log(accounts);
});
console.log(accounts);
```

Comment: When I attempt to return the result, I get the following report on my console:  Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function.                                  
This is confusing to me because in the following documentation, it confirms that web3.eth.getAccounts() is an [async function](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethaccounts).

Comment: For whatever reason, the following code worked:                                                    
var accounts = web3.eth.accounts;
web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0]; 
console.log(web3.eth.defaultAccount);                                                               
Maybe I do not need to use an async function because I am using Ganache on local server: 7545 instead of a real blockchain. What do you think?